# Как в адресе подставить нужные атрибуты (Leaflet)

Tags: javascript, карты, leafletjs

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в URL адресе с которого Leaflet тащит тайлы, поставить нужные папки.

```
const url = `http://localhost/maps3/z{z}/0/x{x}/0/y{y}.png`

const positron = L.tileLayer(url, {
    zoomOffset: 1,
    attribution: cartodbAttribution
}).addTo(map)
```

То есть, в структуре -> `z{z}/0/x{x}/0/y{y}.png` `z{z}` - это масштаб, `0` - папка, которая содержит координаты Х, `x{x}` - папка с соответствующими координатами, `0` опять папка, которая содержит координаты Y, `y{y}.png` - сами тайлы.

Папки между координатами Z и X с z1 до z12 имеют название `0`, а с z12 они уже с разными названиями.

Сразу оговорюсь, что это статичная выгрузка тайлов и только определённого района на карте.

Может кто сталкивался как можно заменить на динамическое определение папок между координатами?!

Пример директорий с тайлами:
[details]

```
/var/www/html/maps3
├── z1
│   └── 0
│       └── x0
│           └── 0
│               └── y0.png
├── z10
│   └── 0
│       └── x310
│           └── 0
│               └── y160.png
├── z11
│   └── 0
│       └── x621
│           └── 0
│               └── y320.png
├── z12
│   └── 1
│       └── x1242
│           └── 0
│               └── y640.png
├── z13
│   └── 2
│       └── x2485
│           └── 1
│               └── y1281.png
├── z14
│   └── 4
│       └── x4970
│           └── 2
│               └── y2563.png
├── z15
│   └── 9
│       ├── x9940
│       │   └── 5
│       │       ├── y5126.png
│       │       └── y5127.png
│       └── x9941
│           └── 5
│               ├── y5126.png
│               └── y5127.png
├── z16
│   └── 19
│       ├── x19879
│       │   └── 10
│       │       ├── y10251.png
...
│       └── x19883
│           └── 10
│               ├── y10251.png
│               └── y10254.png
├── z17
│   └── 38
│       ├── x39760
│       │   └── 20
│       │       ├── y20505.png
...
│       ├── x39762
│       │   └── 20
│       │       ├── y20505.png
│       │       ├── y20506.png
│       │       ├── y20507.png
│       │       └── y20508.png
│       ├── x39763
│       │   └── 20
│       │       ├── y20505.png
│       │       ├── y20506.png
│       │       ├── y20507.png
│       │       └── y20508.png
│       ├── x39764
│       │   └── 20
│       │       ├── y20505.png
│       │       ├── y20506.png
│       │       ├── y20507.png
│       │       └── y20508.png
│       ├── x39765
│       │   └── 20
│       │       ├── y20505.png
│       │       └── y20508.png
│       └── x39766
│           └── 20
│               ├── y20505.png
│               └── y20508.png
├── z18
│   └── 77
│       ├── x79520
│       │   └── 40
│       │       ├── y41011.png
│       │       └── y41017.png
...
│       ├── x79530
│       │   └── 40
│       │       ├── y41011.png
│       │       ├── y41012.png
│       │       ├── y41013.png
│       │       ├── y41014.png
│       │       ├── y41015.png
│       │       ├── y41016.png
│       │       └── y41017.png
│       ├── x79531
│       │   └── 40
│       │       ├── y41011.png
│       │       ├── y41012.png
│       │       ├── y41013.png
│       │       ├── y41014.png
│       │       ├── y41015.png
│       │       ├── y41016.png
│       │       └── y41017.png
│       ├── x79532
│       │   └── 40
│       │       ├── y41011.png
│       │       └── y41017.png
│       └── x79533
│           └── 40
│               ├── y41011.png
│               └── y41017.png
├── z19
│   └── 155
│       ├── x159040
│       │   └── 80
│       │       ├── y82022.png
│       │       ├── y82023.png
├── z2
│   └── 0
│       └── x1
│           └── 0
│               └── y0.png
├── z20
│   └── 310
│       ├── x318081
│       │   └── 160
│       │       ├── y164044.png
│       │       ├── y164045.png
...
│       ├── x318082
│       │   └── 160
│       │       ├── y164044.png
│       │       ├── y164045.png
│               └── y164068.png
├── z21
│   └── 621
│       ├── x636162
│       │   └── 320
│       │       ├── y328088.png
│       │       ├── y328089.png
...
│       ├── x636180
│       │   └── 320
│       │       ├── y328088.png
...
│       ├── x636251
│       │   └── 320
│       │       ├── y328088.png
│       │       ├── y328089.png
│       │       └── y328136.png
│       ├── x636252
│       │   └── 320
│       │       ├── y328088.png
│       │       ├── y328089.png
│       ├── x636253
│       │   └── 320
│       │       ├── y328088.png
│       │       ├── y328089.png
│       ├── x636254
│       │   └── 320
│       │       ├── y328088.png
│       │       ├── y328089.png
│       ├── x636255
│       │   └── 320
│       │       ├── y328088.png
│       │       ├── y328089.png
│       ├── x636256
│       │   └── 320
│       │       ├── y328088.png
│       │       ├── y328089.png
│       ├── x636257
│       │   └── 320
│       │       ├── y328088.png
│       │       ├── y328089.png
│       ├── x636258
│       │   └── 320
│       │       ├── y328088.png
│       │       ├── y328089.png
│       ├── x636259
│       │   └── 320
│       │       ├── y328088.png
│       │       ├── y328089.png
│       ├── x636260
│       │   └── 320
│       │       ├── y328088.png
│       │       ├── y328089.png
│       ├── x636261
│       │   └── 320
│       │       ├── y328088.png
│       │       ├── y328089.png
│       ├── x636262
│       │   └── 320
│       │       ├── y328088.png
│       │       ├── y328089.png
│       ├── x636263
│       │   └── 320
│       │       ├── y328088.png
│       │       ├── y328089.png
│       ├── x636264
│       │   └── 320
│       │       ├── y328088.png
│       │       ├── y328089.png
│       ├── x636265
│       │   └── 320
│       │       ├── y328088.png
│       │       ├── y328089.png
│       ├── x636266
│       │   └── 320
│       │       ├── y328088.png
│       │       ├── y328089.png
│       ├── x636267
│       │   └── 320
│       │       ├── y328088.png
│       │       ├── y328089.png
│       └── x636268
│           └── 320
│               ├── y328088.png
│               ├── y328089.png
├── z3
│   └── 0
│       └── x2
│           └── 0
│               └── y1.png
├── z4
│   └── 0
│       └── x4
│           └── 0
│               └── y2.png
├── z5
│   └── 0
│       └── x9
│           └── 0
│               └── y5.png
├── z6
│   └── 0
│       └── x19
│           └── 0
│               └── y10.png
├── z7
│   └── 0
│       └── x38
│           └── 0
│               └── y20.png
├── z8
│   └── 0
│       └── x77
│           └── 0
│               └── y40.png
└── z9
    └── 0
        └── x155
            └── 0
                └── y80.png
```

[/details]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const map = L.map('mapBla', {
  center: [55.661481, 37.538610],
  minZoom: 0,
  maxZoom: 18,
  attributionControl: false,
  zoomControl: true
})

const url = `/tails/maps2/z{z}/{ix}/x{x}/{iy}/y{y}.png`

const position = L.tileLayer(url, {
    // Определяем дополнительные атрибуты для ссылки путём расчёта по формуле
    ix: args => Math.floor(args.x / 1024),
    iy: args => Math.floor(args.y / 1024),
    zoomOffset: 1
  })
  .addTo(map)

//map.setView([0, 0], 2)
```

```css
.mapBla {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<div id="mapBla" class="mapBla"></div>
```